# Namespaces is forbidden error for a new user

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kind

I added a new user named "hello" to kind cluster with client-certificate-data and client-key-data. When I switch to its context and press the command:

`kubectl get ns development-hello`

I get:

`Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces "development-hello" is forbidden: User "hello" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "development-hello"`

I do not have clusterrolebinding for this user.

Here is a snapshot from kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1   
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:33445
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: hello
  name: hello-kind-kind
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: hello-kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: hello
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Answer (score 4):

A ClusterRole and RoleBinding need to be created for the `hello` user by using the `admin` account.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ns-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespace"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "delete"]    
---    
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ns-rolebinding
  namespace: development-hello
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: hello
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ns-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The kubeconfig file with admin account can be retrieved using below command

```
docker exec -it <kind-control-plane-node-name>

sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain what is the admin account? I used kind-kind user to create the RoleBinding as you wrote but I still get the same error. I assumed kind-kind User has an admin permissions but I seems to be wrong...

Comment: Have updated the answer with details on how to get the kubeconfig with admin account

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it in my case:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```